# Getting published content item out of request["PUBLISHED"] in Plone

Tags: plone, zope

I try to get context object in IPubAfterTraversal hook from event

```
@grok.subscribe(IPubAfterTraversal)
def admin_language_negotiator(event):
    """
    Event handler which pokes the language after traversing and authentication is done, but before rendering.
    """
    # Keep the current request language (negotiated on portal_languages)
    # untouched

    request = event.request

    if not IAddonSpecific.providedBy(request):
        # Add on is not active
        return

    context = request.get("PUBLISHED", None)
```

I'd like to do:

```
   IContentish.providedBy(context) # Check if real content request or CSS/Image request
```

PUBLISHED is not content item context, however:

```
    context
   <FSPageTemplate at /Plone/en/plan/plan/document_view>
```

The PUBLISHED may or may not point to a view. What is the safest way to get published content item object, if any, out of HTTPRequest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plone.app.theming does it like this:

```
def findContext(request):
    """Find the context from the request
    """
    published = request.get('PUBLISHED', None)
    context = getattr(published, '__parent__', None)
    if context is None:
        context = request.PARENTS[0]
    return context
```

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.theming/blob/master/src/plone/app/theming/utils.py#L146

Comment: Works. Here is the full story: https://github.com/miohtama/silvuple/blob/master/silvuple/negotiator.py